# How can I retrieve hyperlinks in a table row with the help of Angular and PHP?

Tags: php, angular

Consider:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th style="width:180px;">Faculty Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_with('a_faculty');"></a></th>
        <th>Award/Fellowship&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_with('a_name');"></a></th>
        <th style="width:120px;text-align:center;">Year&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_with('a_year');"></a></th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in searched = (file | filter:search | orderBy : base :reverse) | beginning_data:(current_grid-1)*data_limit | limitTo:data_limit">
           <td>{{data.a_faculty}}</td>
           <td>{{data.a_name}}</td>
           <td>{{data.a_year}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I am using this, it retrieves only text, no hyperlinks. I want text with hyperlinks.

Comment: How many hyperlinks per row? One? More than one?

Comment: Can you explain better? I'm not understanding what you wan't. Where are the hyperlinks info? Inside interpolation? If so, have you tried to bind href of <a> to data.something?